# Finding least Common ancestor in Binary Tree with o(h^2) for a change

Tags: graph, graph-theory, theory, least-common-ancestor

Before thinking of writing a function to fulfill it, I try to think of an algorithm. h is denoted to be the maximal distance between the main parent to a given node. It should run in o(h^2) which means it should be easier to come up with such an algorithm, but I constantly find myself with o(h) algorithm. I also get confused when it comes to understanding if I am actually doing a h^2 operation. I could really use a lead.

Comment: Why do you *want* a slower algorithm? And if you want a quadratic-time algorithm, why not just run the linear-time algorithm and then busy-loop for h^2 steps?

Comment: I am asked for it. And I want to have a full theoretical comprehension of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest algorithm for LCA would run in `O(h^2)` — make two nested loops, one running over all ancestors of first vertex, the other running over all ancestors of the second, and inside the loop just compare them.

```
a1 = a  // a is the first given vertes
while a1 != nil   // assume root's parent is nil
    a2 = b  // b is the second given vertex
    while a2 != nil 
        if (a1 == a2) 
            compare with current-best solution
        a2 = a2.parent
   a1 = a1.parent
```

So, go up from the first given vertex, that is go through all its ancestors. For each its ancestor `a1`, go from the second given vertex up to root and check whether you meet the `a1` vertex on the way.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am afraid I didn't understand it too well. I have two given vertexes. What do I do with each of them? Denote them a and b. I go from a upwards and always checks if it is b's parent, then I go from b upwards doing the same?

Comment: @Meitar, I've expanded the answer a bit